# NoMethodError if user types in random URL

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When ever a user types in any random string in the websites url ie `localhost:3000/rfgfgh` or `localhost:3000/gfgfgf/fhh` it throws this random error.

I understand why it throws this error since I am checking if the user is `contracter` in the views and if they are display specific contracter code. I'm also using slugs to display contracter specific content. If the user goes to `localhost:3000/contracter` it checks for the slug contracter and then renders the page.

What are some solutions to remove this error? Is it possible to just redirect the user to the home page?

```
NoMethodError in Users#show

undefined method `contractor?' for nil:NilClass

1: <% if @user.contractor? %>
2:  <% title "#{@user.name}" %>
```

Comment: You haven't posted enough to know what the problem is for sure. However, this means that you are calling `myuser.contracter?`, where `myuser` is nil. Perhaps you haven't initialized it, or you are looking for a user that doesn't exist.

Comment: It would be the second option, rails is looking for a user that isn't in the database. How can I redirect the user to the home page if this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error you see, it means that you are calling something like `@myuser.contracter?`, where `@myuser` is nil.

If the user isn't in the database, it will not find the user, and put nil in the `@myuser` object.

To redirect a user to the home page, simply check if the variable is nil in the controller, and redirect if necessary, eg:

```
@myuser = User.find(params[:id]) # or params[:username]
if @myuser.nil? # check if nil
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "User does not exist!" # redirect to home page
end
```